# Hiding nested for loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Is there a built-in function to help hide independent nested for loops?

Since they do not depend on one another to generate the next item a function could take in iterables as arguments and yield the appropriate number of items.

From:

```
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        for z in range(z):
            do_something()
```

to:

```
for i, j, k in iterate_over(range(x), range(y), range(z)):
    do_something()
```

Comment: `itertools.product`

Comment: Sounds pointless.

Comment: as @PHPglue points, if `do_something` doesn't depend on `i,j,k` you may as well use a single loop: `for _ in range(x*y*z):`

Comment: You can write this yourself pretty easily. But `itertools.product` as suggested by @Julien has the advantage that (1) it's a well-known function that any experienced Python dev will understand in your code, and (2) it might be faster than what you'd build yourself.

Comment: @PHPglue Normally you don't use this on three ranges, you use it on some useful pair of sequences where you want the cartesian product (without building the whole list in memory). In other words, it's exactly as useless as a nested loop statement is…

Comment: `import itertools` `x = 15; y = 10; z = 5` `for i, j, k in itertools.product(range(x), range(y), range(z)): print i, j, k`